# Reducing dom elements, can I use span instead of div?

Tags: css, dom, html

I have  several div elements for charts. Yslow is saying to reduce DOM elements.

Can i use:

```
<span class="col1 left"></span><span class="col2 center"></span><span class="col3 right"></span>
```

instead of:

```
<div class="col 1 left"></div><div class="col2 center"></div><div class="col3 right"></div>
```

to reduce DOM elements, or is span a DOM element too?

I've got about 900 in total so far. Any ideas or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it start with `<` and end with `>`? Then it's a DOM element (even the text technically is).

Comment: If you provide a link to your actual site, we might be able to see if you could lose some of those 900 elements.

Comment: No, 900 DOM elements in all. @Simeon Visser cleared things up for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`span` is a DOM element too. So for the number of DOM elements, it won't make a difference. To reduce the number of DOM elements, you'd need to consider whether each element is really necessary.

Can you also create the same visual page with different HTML? Using less elements will make it clear and easier to read. Perhaps you're complicating things too much by adding extra elements that are not really needed.

Comment: @Simeon Visser Now understand what a DOM element I guess I'll have to look at the template and consider better css options or figure out if an element is absolutely necessary.  Thanks.

Comment: It's often possible by using better CSS selectors. You don't need to name each element with a new `span` or `div` around it to style it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe just about any HTML tag becomes a DOM element to your browser.